# Determine if many points are in bounding box

Tags: python, numpy, vector, coordinates, bounding-box

The array `x` denotes a bounding box, delimited by two (x,y) coordinates:

```py
x = np.array([[2, 1], [5, 3]])
```

And the array `p` denotes a collection of points by their (x,y) coordinates:

```py
p = np.array([[3, 2], [6, 4], [3, 4], [4, 2]])
```

For each point in `p`, I want to determine (in one operation) whether it's in the bounding-box `x`, so as to get the following result.

```py
result = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
```

I've though about `np.where()` but not sure how to process the whole collection of points in one operation. Also, wouldn't a purely numerical approach be faster?

EDIT:

I'd be interested as well in the case where multiple bounding boxes are present, such as:

```py
# [[bbox_1], [bbox_2], [bbox_2]]
# with each bbox as [x1 y1 x2 y2]
x = np.array([[2, 1, 5, 3], [2, 2, 4, 6], [0, 4, 3, 2]])
```

with the result being of the form

```py
# [p1_bbox_1, p2_bbox_1, p3_bbox_1, p4_bbox_1], [p1_bbox_2, p2_bbox_2 ...]]
# results not necessarily exact but shape is correct
result = np.array([[True, False, False, True], [True, False, False, False], [False, False, True, False]])
```

A point sitting exactly on a bbox boundary should be considered inside.

Comment: Got doubts again. What about `[3, 4]` and `[4, 2]` from `p[2]` and `p[3]`. Aren't they inside the second box. This is the second row of `result`.

Comment: values are wrong except for the first bounding box — I just made these examples up, let me check if you want me to give the correct values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With slicing and leveraging `broadcasting` -

```
In [24]: ((p>=x[0]) & (p<=x[1])).all(1)
Out[24]: array([ True, False, False,  True])
```

This assumes bounding box array as :

```
[[x1,y1]
 [x2,y2]]
```

If the format is say `[x1,y1,x2,y2]` (1D array) that define the box corners, we could get it like so -

```
((p>=x[:2]) & (p<=x[2:])).all(1)
```

Also, edit `>=` to `>` and so on for exclusiveness on boundaries.

**Extend to multiple boxes**

For multiple boxes in `x` with a format of 2D array :

```
[[B1x1,B1y1,B1x2,B1y2],
 [B2x1,B2y1,B2x2,B2y2], ..
                      ]
```

So, B1 is `box-1`, `B2` is `box-2` and so on, while `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` are the bounding box corners for each box. The solution would be -

```
((p>=x[:,None,:2]) & (p<=x[:,None,2:])).all(2)
```

Comment: this is really neat. how about when there are multiple bounding boxes, e.g. `x = np.array([2, 1, 5, 3], [2, 2, 4, 6], [0, 4, 3, 2]])` — still possible in one operation?

Comment: in this case the output would be in the form `result = np.array([[True, False, False, True], [False, True, False, False], [False, False, True, False]])`

Comment: @Jivan `x` has three rows and 4 columns. What do those mean? How does a 3x4 matrix represent multiple bounding boxes?

Comment: yes, three bounding boxes made of 4 coordinates `x1 y1 x2 y2` — it's just an example though, could be a different shape if needed

Comment: @Jivan Can you add these multiple boxes case into the question? Also, you stated `result[1,1]` to be True. That means `[6,4]` to be in `[2, 2, 4, 6]`, which should be False, right?

Comment: sure I can — yes my mistake `[6, 4]` would be false

Comment: I can see the logic. Thanks very much again.